# The colloquial expression "Here/There I was thinking"

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases, expressions

While I was writing the following text, I wondered how the two slightly different expressions "here I was" and "there I was" might be nuanced in meaning. Also, is it more common to have the word "and" precede the "here/there" to signal more clearly that I'm about to say something opposite to the previous remark?

---

> Ah, I see. The code didn't run because I had a 'break' statement in it. **(And) Here/There I was thinking** that the reason for this error might well be more to do with the duality of the 'if' and 'ternary' statements. Looks like I was of the mark. If I hadn't asked, I would have kept this misunderstanding for a long time to come.

Answer (score 2):

**"And here"** puts it in this moment, while **"And there"** puts it in the past.

This is how I would write it:

"Ah, I see. The code didn't run because I had a 'break' statement in it. I was thinking that the reason for this error might have more to do with the duality of the 'if' and 'ternary' statements. It looks like I was **off** the mark. If I hadn't asked, I would have **retained** this misunderstanding **indefinitely**."

Although it doesn't add substance to the statement, the addition of **"And here"** would not be incorrect, just casual and informal (like **"Ah, I see."**).